# What is the value of the integral $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1+\csc(x))^{k+\frac{1}{2}} \, \,dx$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

When I was messing around with some integrals I got the result that

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1+\csc(x))^{k+\frac{1}{2}} \, \,dx = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Now I would like to solve the integral, but I don't really have any idea (I wonder whether it's possible at all?). I tried to change $1+\csc(x)$ in terms of sines and cosines (using [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-integral-of-displaystyle-int-sqrt-1+-csc-x-mathrm-dx)) so that one gets

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1+\csc(x))^{k+\frac{1}{2}} \, \,dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)(1-\sin(x))}\right)^{k+\frac{1}{2}} \, \,dx$$

...but I can't see how this would lead anywhere.

Comment: Just out of curiosity : how did you get the nice $\frac {\pi^2}6$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I like messing around with integrals that have a known value (["Integral milking"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821112/integral-milking)), and so I used [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251046/how-to-show-the-following-integral-int-0-frac-pi2-cot-1-sqrt1-csc) result and used the taylor series for $\cot^{-1}(x)$. I might have done some error tho...

Comment: $\large\int$ diverges for $\large k = 1,2,3,\ldots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is a problem around $x=0$ except for $k=0$. Using Taylor series and bionmial expansion
$$(1+\csc(x))^{k+\frac{1}{2}}=\frac 1 {x^k}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)
   \sqrt{x}+O\left(x^{3/2}\right)\right) $$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(-1)^kz^{2k+1}}{2k+1}=\arctan z$, your series is $\int_0^{\pi/2}\arctan\sqrt{1+\csc x}dx$. This is $\infty$ as @ClaudeLeibovici noted, because for small $x$ the integrand is $\sim x^{-1/2}$. It's more interesting if we delete the $k=0$ case, giving $\int_0^{\pi/2}(\arctan\sqrt{1+\csc x}-\sqrt{1+\csc x})dx$, [which WA can only numerically evaluate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+arctan+sqrt%281%2Bcsc+x%29+-+sqrt%281%2Bcsc+x%29+from+0+to+pi%2F2).

Comment: Your WA link provides a numerical computation but no closed form.  However, your WA link is (apparently) to a definite rather than indefinite integral.  How do you know, based on the results given by your WA link, that there is no closed form answer to the corresponding indefinite integral?

Comment: @user2661923 [Good question](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+arctan%28sqrt%281%2Bcsc+x%29%29-sqrt%281%2Bcsc+x%29).